# Mutual repulsion force in js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I have a 1-dimensional dataset (a list of elements with only a horizontal position (+ circle radius)).

I want to implement a simple layout algorithm to show this dataset as circles in a scale.
The problem is the collisions.

[image]

I want to implement a "simple" repulsion force to avoid collisions. I don't mind the circles won't have a precise position anymore.
The result I'm looking for is simple as that:

[image]

I'm not using D3, it is plain js (and svg.js), where to start looking for theoretical information about this layout? What is the common name with which this force is referred to? Is there any example of similar things?

Comment: it is not that simple, the force should move the circles on the left and right sides both, minimising the difference between the drawn position and the real position of every circle.

Comment: @Leonid that would be the second step of the algorithm in which I move the circles vertically. But I'll handle that after the first horizontal-only implementation..

Comment: Once I rearrange an overlapping cluster, of course, I could cause more collisions. That is why I'm talking about a balancing force, not a trivial layout that increases/decreases the positions individually.

Comment: The current algorithm is way too simple at the moment.
1. find overlapping groups 2. rearrange them with enough space (the sum of radius + a bit of margin). Even making this one iterative won't be enough. I'm afraid there is no good solution without using physics.

Comment: I don't actually get your question: "Do you mind to change positions of all elements together as a single system? Not individually?" I would care about the actual animation and movement once I know where to move the nodes. We are talking about the algorithm, which is the step before the actual application of the new positions. Everything else in your comment sounds right tho.

Comment: I just need the new position, I would care about animation in a different step (all together, I don't care about showing the animation of each rearrangement, that is not the point of the visualisation). The dataset is as simple as `[{pos:10, size:5}, {pos:50, size:10}, {pos:150, size:5}]` in a range of `0-300`.

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion. 
A collision (between 1st and 2nd node) would be in this case
`[{pos:10, size:5}, {pos:20, size:10}, {pos:150, size:5}]`

a possible output could be 
`[{pos:7, size:5}, {pos:22, size:10}, {pos:150, size:5}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added `min_gap` for minimum margin between elements. So the solution is to move two intersected elements with most intersected distance on a small step at a time.

```js
const elements = [{pos:10, radius:5}, {pos:15, radius: 20}, {pos:20, radius:10}, {pos:150, radius:5}];

const field_size = [0, 300];

const min_gap = 5;
const step = 1;

moveIntersected(elements);

console.log(elements);

function detectCollisions(arr=[]){
    const result = [];
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
        let dist = (arr[i+1].pos - arr[i+1].radius) - (arr[i].pos + arr[i].radius);
        if(dist < min_gap){
            result.push([i + 0.5, dist]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function moveIntersected(arr=[]){

    const collisions = detectCollisions(arr);
    if(collisions.length < 1) return;
    
    const most_intersected = collisions.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1])[0];
    const left = arr[Math.floor(most_intersected[0])];
    const right = arr[Math.ceil(most_intersected[0])];
    
    if(left.pos - left.radius - step >= field_size[0]){
        left.pos -= step;
    } else {
        right.pos += step*2;
    }
    
    if(right.pos + right.radius + step <= field_size[1]){
        right.pos += step;
    } else {
        left.pos -= step*2;
    }
    moveIntersected(arr);
}
```

Comment: Result distance between two elements maybe bigger on `2*step - 1` - now it is 1. That's because even if intersection is 1 we move on 1 step each element (or on 2 steps one of them).

Comment: wow! I wasn't asking for the whole solution! Thanks a lot! Honestly, I thought it would have been more complex, that is why I opened this question. In my first implementation, I used to detect overlapping groups and rearrange them in the context of their own group, not just pairs of nodes like you have done. I think that was the first mistake that lead me to think the solution was way more complex. I hope we covered all the possible overlapping cases! I'm going to do an extensive test on this! Thanks again.

Comment: Hopefully you will add some tests to not enter an eternal recursion)) There is many things to rewrite - it's not a whole solution at all)) Thanks.

Comment: the eternal recursion is just 1 point, another (simple) thing is to make sure rearranged nodes won't move outside the visible area (left and right boundaries). Another one is to add the vertical movement in case there is no "good" horizontal solution. I may need to turn this into a genetic-ish algorithm.

Comment: I've added the outside control. In the example, first element would move out left otherwise. And the goal exactly was to add vertical movement in future. That's because I move the most_intersected at a step. After the step you may sum the gaps between elements. If there is no space - lift up one of most_intersected on a step, calculate new distance between them and etc.

Comment: I see, thanks again!